# How to unfold lists in DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
center    status     devices
1     Green      [d1, d2]
1     Green      [d5, d1, d2]
2     Green      []
3     Green      [d5, d6]
```

I need to unfold lists in the column `devices`. The goal is to group data by `center` and `device`, and then count the number of observations per group.

The expected result would be the following one:

```
center   device   count
1        d1       2
1        d2       2
1        d5       1
3        d5       1
3        d6       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First flatten `list`s and then aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
#create Series
s = df.set_index('center')['devices']
#create DataFrame, reshape by stack and conver MultiIndex to columns
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).stack().reset_index()
df.columns= ['center','i','devices']

#aggregate count
df = df.groupby(['center','devices']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   center device  count
0       1     d1      2
1       1     d2      2
2       1     d5      1
3       3     d5      1
4       3     d6      1
```

Another solution for improve performance:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'devices' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['devices'].tolist())), 
    'center' : df['center'].values.repeat(df['devices'].str.len())
})


df = df.groupby(['center','devices']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   center devices  count
0       1      d1      2
1       1      d2      2
2       1      d5      1
3       3      d5      1
4       3      d6      1
```

Comment: I tried this approach on my real data, but in `center` column I can only see one value. If I do `output[output["center"]==2]`, then the output is empty. But if I do `df[df["center"]==2]`, then I get rows. Do you know why it may happen?

Comment: @Tatik - hmmm, here is empty list for group `2`, so this row is removed from data in output.

Answer (score 2):

Using [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) after filter the empty list out then `groupby` `size`

```
unnesting(df[df.devices.astype(bool)],['devices']).groupby(['center','devices']).size().reset_index(name='count')
Out[214]: 
   center devices  count
0       1      d1      2
1       1      d2      2
2       1      d5      1
3       3      d5      1
4       3      d6      1
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```

Comment: @jezrael yep , you are right ~ thank you for helping me :-)

Comment: @jezrael when I notice there is empty list , I guess , the op already excluded the `np.nan`, but this is only base on my assumption , which is not reliable